# Split SQL Column to Multiple Rows in HTML Table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say my `datatable` retrieves column with value "SAGAR - SAGAR"

```
DataTable dtOutput;
dtOutput = Generix.getATMDetails(sATM);//Retrieves data
```

I can convert my datatable to HTML Table for display in HTML Page. 
How can i convert one of its Column into multi line format while displaying it in HTML Page

E.g: dtOutput (data)

```
Comments (Column Header)
SAGAR - SAGAR - SAGAR
```

now while displaying it in HTML page it should be like this

```
SAGAR
SAGAR
SAGAR
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? It's also not clear what you're trying to do. What have you tried?

Comment: Heads up - I removed the SQL tag, since your code is strictly C#.  Consider changing title.

Comment: Convert it to an array of strings by calling String.Split() and manipulating from there? Use String.replace to replace " - " with html BR tags?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Its a Web Application in C# ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a new line by adding `</ br>`. There are several ways to do this.

- from the `select query` using `REPLACE(comments, ' - ' , '</ br>')` 
  (if you are in sql server)
- within the `datatable`
- during the `data binding` as follows

  ```
  <%# Eval("comments").ToString().Replace(" - ","</ br>") %>
  ```